# Feeding a UITableViewController calculated values

Tags: core-data, lazy-loading, uitableview, average

Very quick question.  I need to feed a UITableViewController daily averages calculated from multiple objects with an NSNumber attribute (each object is timestamped, with 8-10 objects per day usually).  Is there any straightforward way to calculate on the fly using my own version of lazy loading (I would average data in chronological order till I had a screenful of daily averages) or should I just take the easy way out and maintain an Averages entity pre-populated with averages for all possible days, which I present conventionally in my UITableViewController?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how long the calculation takes? Why not just calculate it in the UITableViewDataSource method that asks for the cellForRowAtIndexPath? Unless it takes time to calculate - thereby causing a delay in populating the values onscreen - I'd say there's no harm in calculating on the fly.

There's plenty of other places to do the calculation. You could do it on app startup, or on loading the view. You could even start an NSOperation that does it in the background with the controller as a delegate that tells it when to reloadData.

Comment: Interesting thoughts... I just have this problem of mismatched inputs and outputs -- row 4 could need to show the average values of objects 4-6 or the average values of objects 40-60. Maybe on view load I could compute the correlations so I know what values to average when the controller asks about a given row in the table.  Or maybe I should keep a Correlations entity so I don't have to recompute every time the table is viewed. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

You should do a fetch by value (see [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6)) and then use the `@avg` collections operator on the attribute name.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do a fetch by value for every possible date range (24-hour period) to get daily averages, though?

Comment: Yes, but your just fetching the values of that specific attribute  so it's a lightweight operation. You don't instantiate any managed objects or maintain an object graph so it quick and low memory.